# Stack on top of the each other the multiple selected items in Angular-Material?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Here is a [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/jjsub/pen/KzvgKM) for the behavior that I have.

The multiple selected options are being stack one next to the other, but the problem with this is once the user select more and more options the options text overflow the text box of a form with a set width.

I need to find a way to stack the selected options on top of each other once the end of the text box is reach therefor keep all the options stack with in the form box.

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
      .module('MyApp')
      .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
        this.likedAnimals = ["mouse", "dog"];
        this.animals = ["mouse", "dog", "cat", "bird",
                        "LongAnnnnnnimal","LongerrrrrrrrrrrrText"];
  });
})();
```

```html
<div>
  <md-input-container>
    <md-select multiple ng-model="ctrl.likedAnimals" placeholder="please select">
      <md-option ng-repeat="a in ctrl.animals" value="{{a}}">{{a}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify `width` in `px` to set the the exact width of `md-select` rather than specifying width to `md-option`. See the below link.

http://codepen.io/next1/pen/xVLEpy

```
<md-input-container style="background-color:cyan">
<md-select flex style="background-color:yellow;width:200px" multiple ng-model="ctrl.likedAnimals" placeholder="please select"  >
  <md-option ng-repeat="a in ctrl.animals" value="{{a}}">{{a}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: With this change I can't see all the selected options, I would like to be able to auto change the hight of the tex box so that way they can stack one on top of each other.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to display it in column kind of layout ?

Comment: Yes column 2 x 2 stack on top of each other.

Comment: I don't think there is any control for that but you can use that model variable to display it separately.

Comment: One solution can be like this. You can specify the height of `md-content`. I must say that you should better use pre-processed array not the kind of hack I used in this example. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/YqxpOZ

Comment: @JRod just check the new version of the library. `select` got some things you needed.